# Canadian Cities as points

Tags: data, canada

I'm looking for a dataset with Canadian cities as points. I only need this for the Greater Toronto and Hamilton Area (GTHA).

Comment: To source data, pleast try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you contact Greater  Toronto and Hamilition Area GIS Department ? They should be able to give you ...Otherwise go here https://www.diva-gis.org/Data or https://gadm.org/download_country.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick web search takes me to https://guides.library.ualberta.ca/c.php?g=301218&p=5103668 and clicking through a few links to [this FTP folder](https://ftp.maps.canada.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/framework_cadre/North_America_Atlas10M/popplaces/?_gl=1*1uf57zc*_ga*Njc5OTg2ODA4LjE3MDkyNjUzNjY.*_ga_C2N57Y7DX5*MTcwOTI2NTM5Mi4xLjAuMTcwOTI2NTM5Mi4wLjAuMA..).

From there, you can download [popPlaces_v2.zip](https://ftp.maps.canada.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/framework_cadre/North_America_Atlas10M/popplaces/popPlaces_v2.zip)

This includes populated places in all of North America, but you can filter it on country, state and/or population class.

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @Emily [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)